# CSS element changes taking no effect

Tags: css, element

Usually when I go to write custom CSS for a site, I use Inspect Element to view the contents of certain, well, elements. And it usually I just add the identifier for that line, and punch in some custom commands like "border: none;" but I keep coming across elements that don't appear to have any real name other than just "element" and for some reason NO changes I make to some of these "elements" actually work or get applied.

For instance: There were disgusting white borders on a table, and since I couldn't target the specific element, I added this to the top of my document:

```
* {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Which, one would assume would work. And, surely, it does! For everything except the element I'm trying to change. I still can't quite figure out how I'm expected to change this element, when something that encompasses the entire file STILL can't forcefully change it. Can someone explain this to me?

Edit:

I'm not sure what you expect me to show you, since I explained it here. These images show my inspector open and you already have above my custom code implemented through Stylish plugin/ custom CSS file.

[image: First]
and 
[image: Second]

Just to reiterate, instead of saying "element" it usually gives me a valid name to go by, such as "table#first", and I wrote

```
* {
    border: none !important;
}
```

to counter the border it has applied, but it won't take the change. I imagine it has something to do with the !important in the original border but I'm not sure what to do.

Edit:

I added

```
table[style] {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Which I expected to work, but still comes up the same as when I added the first block of code I explained, it crosses it out in the inspector and doesn't take effect.

Comment: can u include live url?

Comment: You're going to have to show us some code if you want any help. There is literally nothing we can do  without it.

Comment: Alright, I updated the question to include responses and more information. Please review it and get back to me.

Answer (score 1):

in this case the inline styling is overriding the styles in the css file. to fix this i suggest you giving that table a class and then style it in the css file.

btw: css stands for cascading style sheet meaning the styles that come at the bottom will overwrite the styles that come at the top of the file

so it will look something like this

html:

```
<table class="mytable">
  <!-- content -->
</table>
```

css:

```
.mytable {
    border: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216)
    margin-top 10px;
{

* {
    border: none;
}
```

try to only use !important as a last resort to overwrite a style that isnt working

Comment: Could you please elaborate on giving it a class and styling that particular class? Thanks!

Comment: How would I implement the HTML? I'm editing custom CSS for a foreign site. Unless of course you're asking me to do one or the other, but then I'm not sure how declaring ".mytable" gets attached to any actual table. Sorry, I never actually studied these web languages fully, I mostly learned by tinkering things I've already seen.

Comment: all u have to do is put class="mytable" in the html.

Comment: <table class="mytable">

Comment: I imagine my point was, I'm not entirely certain how I am to edit the HTML, especially given that it's a foreign site. It's not a site I own and wrote all files for, that is.

Comment: well then you are pretty much out of luck

Answer (score 0):

`element` is the DOM inspector's way of telling you that the styles are being applied inline, to the element itself - either directly in the HTML or via JavaScript.

You can work around this by doing the following (inspired by [this](https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/) post at css-tricks.com):

```
/* 
You'll likely want to use a specific selector in order 
to prevent these styles from being applied to _all_ 
tables. 
*/

table[style] {
   border: none !important;
}
```

This is a last resort, though. You should address this issue in a more holistic way, by moving any inline styles which aren't absolutely necessary (e.g. based on calculations done by JS or something computed on the back-end) into your stylesheet, if possible.

Comment: Moving them into the stylesheet? With fear of sounding unbearably incompetent, I shall now inquire as to what you mean.

Comment: Those `element` styles are either embedded in the HTML or coming from JavaScript. If possible, you should move them out of the HTML/JS and into your stylesheet. The only (technical) reason you'd be unable to do that, is if they're being generated dynamically.

Comment: Yes of course, but how do you define "move them"? I'm still not sure what you want me, specifically, to do.

Comment: Remove the code which is creating those inline styles (from the dynamic template (erb, php, etc.), static HTML, JavaScript, etc.); insert any of the relevant styles (which previously had been inside the `style` attribute) into your stylesheet.

Comment: I don't know how I am to remove that particular code.